# Relation made on calculated field

Tags: django, django-models

Let's assume i have a models.py like this:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = char...
    code = int...
    email = email...
    evaluations = fk(Evaluation) <-----

class Evaluation(models.Model):
    date = date...
    points = int...
    emp_code = char... <-----
```

Is it possible to do a relation based on a computed field?

I mean in the DB I can not store the `emp_code` from `Evaluation` in plain text so I have a function to hide the code but I don't know how to make the relationship based on a function.

Edit 1:
To clarify some questions: employee.code could be the primary key since its a unique field.
emp_code MUST be hashed. i CANNOT save it in plain text.

i dont need employee.evaluations like a field, it could be some sort of function or whatever that make a comparision based on a processed attribute

Lets assume i have employee.code = 1234, after hashing it comes out as 'abcdef' i would like to get employee object with code = 1234 and all evaluations for emp_code = 'abcdef'

Comment: This isn't clear at all. ForeignKeys point to the primary key of the Evaluation, not the emp_code. (But it's also not clear why you can't store the emp_code.)

Comment: You don't seem to need the `evaluations` field at all. Having a foreign key from `Evaluation` to `Employee` is sufficient. Here you can find more on [relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/).

Comment: Which field is the primary key of `Employee`? That's what you should be linking to from `Evaluation`

Comment: @DanielRoseman this was just an example but what i want to store is a kind of sensitive data that even DB Admin shouldnt see...

Comment: @ceterre - If you want to hide sensitive data, encrypt it. Don't obfuscate the database relationship, it will only cause you problems later on.

Comment: You cannot hide the relation between an evaluation and an employee. If Django knows about the relation, your DBAs will too. If you hide if from them, you hide it from Django as well, and then you can have fun matching the tables manually on a printout :). What you can do is encrypt the details of the evaluation records (and potentially of the employee records) as @Tony said.